# Refresh page while navigating to it on back button press

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to build a xamarin forms app. I need refresh my page when user presses android device back button press. I tried to use OnAppearing method, but its not invoked when page is displayed on back button press. Is there  any method that gets called when a page is displayed from modal stack? 
Or Why OnAppearing method only called on initial launch?
Thanks.

Comment: I got the problem resolved by updating xamarin forms version. For previous versions, as a work around I used a refresh method of page on back button press to give same effect of OnAppearing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh your page I suggest MVVM architecture with bindings:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

But this takes some time to learn, there are some other ways to do this for example:

1.- Sending the objects you want to refresh on the next views as parameters.

2.- Create static methods to refresh your UI.

3.- Doing Callbacks/Delegates or Commands in order to refresh your view:

https://blog.xamarin.com/simplifying-events-with-commanding/

Comment: I need to refresh page when user returns from platform specific page created through intent, in that case if user press back button I need to refresh my page

Comment: For example, I used api to display settings and made some change and pressed back button, i need to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works perfect:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            //Write the code of your page here
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.